# MySQL query to return year, month and total rows for each year

Tags: mysql, date

I have a database of articles, and want to make an archive nav. I want to query individual month/years in the database and also how many months were found for each year. For example:

```
2013 | November | 3
2013 | October  | 3
2013 | September| 3
2012 | February | 2
2012 | January  | 2
2011 | January  | 1
2010 | February | 2
2010 | January  | 2
2009 | April    | 4
2009 | March    | 4
2009 | February | 4
2009 | January  | 4
```

How do I go about doing this?

Comment: You'll need to show us the schema or at least what you've tried.

Comment: GROUP BY combined with the YEAR, MONTH, and MONTHNAME functions should do it.

Answer (score 0):

You need a table to index to. I suggest the following algorithm:

1. Create a temporary table with all the months in one column, and years for your search in another. You can create an index on these two columns for efficiency, if this is something you'll use for other applications. You can also query your records to find the years you need to search (create a set of the available years unless you plan to add records that will be outside of the set).
2. For each ij pair in the table you created in step 1, count the number of records in your articles table that match the month and year condition for ij.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use something like this: To group by year,month + count months

**For example**

```
SELECT *,count(MONTH(date_field)) as totalCount FROM table GROUP BY YEAR(date_field),MONTH(date_field)
```